# How can I migrate an app deployed with React Native to Flutter?

Tags: flutter, react-native, migrate

I have an app developed with React Native and I want to update it with Flutter. I have a concern about this process: how can I maintain the data stored in the local SQLite database even after updating to Flutter? Is there a way to do this?